# How to use "neq" in Gremlin-Python?

Tags: python, gremlin

I have a **Gremlin query** which works from Gremlin console

```
g.V("p1").as("this").out("ContributedTo").in("ContributedTo").where(neq("this")).groupCount()
```

I want to use it from a Python script

```
from __future__ import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('wss://neptunedbcluster.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin','g'))

g.V('p1').as_('this').out('ContributedTo').in_('ContributedTo').where(__.neq('this')).groupCount()
```

And I get an **error**:

```
AttributeError: type object '__' has no attribute 'neq'
```

How should I express Gremlin 'neq' in Python?

Answer (score 6):

`neq` is part of the `P` class, so I should import it and use it

```
from __future__  import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P

from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('wss://neptunedbcluster.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin','g'))

g.V('p1').as_('this').out('ContributedTo').in_('ContributedTo').where(P.neq('this')).groupCount()
```